# Query issue with selecting GROUP_CONCAT where FIND_IN_SET

Tags: mysql, group-concat, find-in-set

Can somebody help me clarify what I'm doing wrong here? The query runs fine without the "AND FIND_IN_SET(40, tags) > 0"

Query error: Unknown column 'tags' in 'where clause' - Invalid query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `tbltickets`.`ticketid` AS `tbltickets.ticketid`, 
  CASE company 
   WHEN "" THEN (
     SELECT CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname) FROM tblcontacts 
     WHERE userid = tblclients.userid and is_primary = 1) 
   ELSE company END as company, 
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ",") 
   FROM tbltags_in JOIN tbltags ON tbltags_in.tag_id = tbltags.id 
   WHERE rel_id = tbltickets.ticketid and rel_type="ticket" 
   ORDER by tag_order ASC) as tags,
 `tbltickets`.`status` AS `tbltickets.status`,
 `tbltickets`.`date` AS `tbltickets.date`,
  tbltickets.userid,statuscolor

FROM   tbltickets  

LEFT JOIN tblticketstatus ON tblticketstatus.ticketstatusid = tbltickets.status 
LEFT JOIN tblclients ON tblclients.userid = tbltickets.userid

WHERE  (tbltickets.date BETWEEN "2019-12-03" AND "2020-01-03") 
  AND FIND_IN_SET(40, tags) > 0

ORDER BY tbltickets.date DESC

LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: You can't use a derived column in the WHERE clause. Move it to a HAVING clause: `HAVING FIND_IN_SET(40, tags) > 0` before ORDER BY.

Comment: @forpas That did it! if you want to post an answer I can accept it for you

Comment: Fine if it is solved. This question has been asked and answered many times, so there is no need for a new answer.